# How to pass startup directory to emacs as parameter

Tags: emacs, batch-file

Let's say, I have emacs on Windows. What I would like to do is to run emacs from the cmd and have my startup directory as default directory in emacs.

I already put the emacs dir into my PATH variable, so I am able to execute 'runemacs' from anywhere in my cmd. But the default directory in emacs does not equal to the startup directory  of emacs. C-x C-f still points me to 'c:\emacs' which, in turn, is specified in emacs config 
(setq default-directory "C:/emacs").

What should I do to have default directory pointing to the startup directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
(add-to-list
 'command-switch-alist
 '("-cwd" . (lambda (x) (setq default-directory (or x (getenv "PWD"))))))
```

In your .emacs file, and create an alias for `emacs -cwd`, or, if I understand it correct, on Windows it would be `runemacs -cwd`. Also, iirc, on Windows it's CWD, not PWD. Well, the meaning of this piece of code is:

- add a function to handle a custom argument to Emacs, namely `-cwd`.
- when trigged, get the value of environment's current working directory and set `default-directory` to whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the line `(setq default-directory "C:/emacs")` from your config, doesn't it do exactly what you are asking for?

Comment: Strange, it doesn't do that here. What about if you run `emacs -Q`?